# How do GC work in middle of scope

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have code like:

```
public void foo()
{
    Object x = new LongObject();
    doSomething(x);
    //More Code

    // x is never used again
    // x = null helps GB??
    Object x2 = new LongObject();
    doSomething(x2);
}
```

I would like that memory alocated by x could be free by GC if it's needed. But I don't know if set to null is necesary or compiler do it.

Comment: No. The GC doesn't really need your help. Let GC concentrate on the garbage and you can concentrate on the programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions literally, the compiler (speaking of source code to bytecode compiler) never inserts `null` assignments, but still, assigning a variable to `null` is not necessary—*usually*.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655916/2711488) explains, scope is a compile time thing and formally, an object is eligible to garbage collection, if it can not “[be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1-200)”. But there is no guaranty about which eligible object will be identified by a particular implementation. As the linked answer also explains, JIT compiled code will only keep references to objects which will be subsequently accessed. This may go even further than you expect, allow garbage collection of objects that look like being in use in the source code, as runtime optimization may transform the code and reduce actual memory accesses.

But in interpreted mode, the analysis will not go so far and there might be object references in the current stack frame preventing the collection of the referent, despite the variable is not being used afterwards or even out of scope in the source code. There is no guaranty that switching from interpreted to compiled code while the method is executed is capable of getting rid of such a dangling references. It’s even unlikely that the hotspot optimizer considers compiling `foo()` when the actual heavy computation happens within `doSomething`.

Still, this is rarely an issue. Running interpreted happens only during the initialization or first time execution and even if these objects are large, there’s rarely a problem if such an object gets collected a bit later than it could. An average application consists of millions of objects.

However, if you ever think there could be an issue, you can easily fix this, without assigning `null` to the variable. Limit the scope:

```
public void foo()
{
    {
        Object x = new LongObject();
        doSomething(x);
        //More Code
    }
    {
        Object x2 = new LongObject();
        doSomething(x2);
    }
}
```

Other than assigning `null`, limiting the scope of variables to the actual use is improving the source code quality, even in cases where it has no impact on the compiled code. While the scope is purely a source code thing, it can have an impact on the bytecode though. In the code above, compilers will reuse the location of `x` within the stack frame to store `x2`, so no dangling reference to the first `LongObject` exists during the second `doSomething` execution.

As said, this is rarely needed for memory management and improving source code quality should be driving you decisions, not attempts to help the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

In point of fact, the JIT does liveness analysis on references (which at bytecode level are stored as slots in the current frame). If a reference is never again read from, its slot can be reused, and the JIT will know that. It is completely possible for an object to be garbage collected while a variable that refers to it is still in lexical scope, so long as the compiler and JIT are able to prove that the variable will never again be dereferenced.

The point is: *scope* is a construct of the *language*, and specifies what a name like `x` means at any point in the text of the program code that it occurs. *Lifetime* is a property of objects, and the JIT and GC manage that -- often in non-obvious ways.

Remember that the JIT can recompile your code while it's running, and will optimize your code as it sees what happens when it executes. Unless you're *really* certain you know what you're doing, don't try to outsmart the JIT. Write code that is *correct* and let the JIT do its job, and only worry about it if you have evidence that the JIT hasn't done its job well enough.